# How to export Typescript class in Node.js with parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

What I need is Typescript equivalent of

```
require('mytypescriptfile')(optionsObject);
```

But TS code:

```
export class Animal {
 name: string;
 public bark(): string {
     return "bark " + this.name;
 }
 constructor(color:string) {    }
}
```

Produces this JS code:

```
"use strict";
var Animal = (function () {
function Animal(color) {
}
Animal.prototype.bark = function () {
    return "bark " + this.name;
};
return Animal;
}());
exports.Animal = Animal;
```

No place for parameter in generated function. How do I do it?

Comment: so you need to convert typescript to commonjs pattern.... right.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myTypescriptModule = require('myCOMPILEDtypescriptfile.js');

const whatIWant = new myTypescriptModule.Animal('red')
```